# When trying to create a trigger in RDS I get an error about binary logging

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When trying to create a trigger in RDS, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1419 (HY000): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is
enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators
variable)
```

Is there a way to get SUPER privileges or to disable binary logging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to get SUPER privileges, but there is a way to disable binary logging (thereby removing the need to have SUPER privileges for creating triggers). This is done by setting the variable [log_bin_trust_create_function_creators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators) to 1.

1. [Create a new RDS Parameter Group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html). Alternatively, you may modify your current parameter group (if its not the default parameter group) and skip steps 3-5.
2. Change the value of `log_bin_trust_create_function_creators` to 1 for that parameter group
3. Also change any parameters that have non-default values in the parameter group that your RDS instance is currently using. This is necessary because an RDS instance can only be associated with one parameter group
4. Modify your RDS instance so that it uses your new parameter group
5. Wait for the parameter group change to show in the event log
6. Restard the RDS instance. `log_bin_trust_create_function_creators` is labeled as dynamic vairable, and therefore shouldn't require a restart, but I have always needed to restart the RDS instance for the change to take effect. Perhaps there is another way but I haven't found it.

Comment: Very good. +1. I thought you had to export and reimport. I am still evaluating RDS. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: That was very helpful @JustinY, issuing a reboot did the trick. Too bad that AWS forces the need for an RDS reboot for a dynamic variable change.